# How to load the view page according to the condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

i have two radio button and one check box..If the radio button alone is checked i want to load one view page(Receipt_view) if both radio button and check box is checked i want to load another view page(Receipt_View1)...My problem is if both radio button and check box is checked i get the output as 2 view pages(that is both the view pages are loaded both Receipt_view and Receipt_view 1 are loaded) but i want Receipt_view1 to be loaded when both the radio button and check box is checked..
Controller Code:

```
    if ($this->input->post('all'))
        {
        $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
  $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        $data['query'] = $query;
        $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);

}

    if($this->input->post('all'))
    {
        if($this->input->post('item')){

        if ($this->input->post('all'))
        {
            if($this->input->post('item')){
            $this->db->where('billdate >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('billdate <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('vno,Prdtname,Qty,bundle');
        $this->db->from('purchaseitem');
            $this->db->order_by("vno", "asc");
            //$this->db->join('purchasebill', 'purchasebill.no = purchaseitem.billno','left outer');
            //$this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.pcode = purchasebill.partyname');
            $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = purchaseitem.Product_Code','left outer');
            $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
            $data['query'] = $query;
            $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
            $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
            $this->db->select();
            $this->db->from('purchasebill');
            $this->db->order_by('voucherno');
            $this->db->group_by('voucherno');
            $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
            $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
            $data['query1'] = $query;
            $this->load->view('Receipt_View1',$data);

    }}
if($this->input->post('selected'))
    {

        if($name = $this->input->post('businessType'))
        {
            $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->where('PName',$name);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        //$this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left outer');
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
        $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
  $data['query'] = $query;
  $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);

      }
}
```

Html Page:

```
<input type="radio" class='rd'name="all" value="op1" checked="">All
<input type="radio" name="selected" class='rd' value="op2"> Selected
<input type="checkbox" name="item" >Item description
```

All and selected is the radio button name and item is the check box name..Help me to solve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what happens when neither of them is checked, so I'm not mentioning this case here, but you can do something like:

```
if ($this->input->post('all')) {
    //do something with purchasebill, no need to repeat the code
    //check if the checkbox is checked:
    if($this->input->post('item')) {
       // do something with purchaseitem
       $this->load->view('Receipt_View1',$data);
    } else {
       $this->load->view('Receipt_View',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain your comment in more detail? Show the html of the page and point us to the radiobuttons and the checkbox. In the question you mentioned one radio and one checkbox, am I correct?

Comment: Sorry i mentioned it wrongly..i have added html page in my edited post

Answer (score 0):

write functions in 'else' block , your not using 'else' with if condition..

Comment: Tried but getting 2 view pages as a result

Comment: add one more if condition inside if condition for load second view page

Comment: Tried but it does not load any data..I get blank page as a result......

Answer (score 0):

By using elseif and && operator we can load according to the condition

```
    if ($this->input->post('all'))
        {
        $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
  $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        $data['query'] = $query;
        $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);

}

    else if(($this->input->post('all')) &&($this->input->post('item')))
    {




        $this->db->select('vno,Prdtname,Qty,bundle');
        $this->db->from('purchaseitem');
            $this->db->order_by("vno", "asc");
            $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = purchaseitem.Product_Code','left outer');
            $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
            $data['query'] = $query;
            $this->load->view('Receipt_View1',$data);

    }}
else if($this->input->post('selected'))
    {

        if($name = $this->input->post('businessType'))
        {
            $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->where('PName',$name);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        //$this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left outer');
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
        $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
  $data['query'] = $query;
  $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);

      }
}
```